# PHP5, SQL database and web host server

Tags: security, desktop, web-hosting

1. what configurations can make differ between a local host server like phpMyadmin and a web hosting server
2. is it possible or convenient if a laptop [instead a desktop computer] is converted into a serverHost
3. is there a php script provided for an automatic backup or sync of files
4. in a web-based application, which is better? running the codes first in the localhost or directly upload the codes in the webhost ??

waaa .. .i need some response to this

Comment: If you have four distinct questions to ask, please make four posts, not just one.

Comment: Most obscure question I ever encountered on SO.

Comment: One question at a time.  Re-post and then I'll answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Default configurations on localhost servers are almost the same as the configurations hosting-companies offer.
2. Ofcourse!
3. Just google, back-up is always possible.. hosting-companies gives 90% of the time a tool in the controlpanel to backup your website.
4. Always test on localhost then apply on the webserver and watch the results.

Comment: People don't post comments like that ;) Everbody has to start somewhere... you started as a noobscripter too